# How to unwrap a curved mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am in need of help unwrapping the rifle butt of the shotgun that I am making. I already added some seams on the back part and it seems to be done well (correct me if I am wrong, but I am still new at advanced unwrapping). The problem is when I unwrap including the majority of the mesh, it is all messed up and stretched (SEE IMAGE 1).

[image: IMAGE 1]

I found a tip on the internet that you need to add some loop cuts, but when I did, it just unwrapped it as a circle (SEE IMAGE 2).

[image: IMAGE 2]

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

- I will use this to export for Substance Painter, please guide me in unwrapping this in a way that will be usable in Substance Painter if needed.
- Blend file: [image]

Comment: We can't actually see any seams on your model They should be shown in Red. As far as the distortion is concerned, did you apply the scale to the model in Object mode (Ctrl - A > Scale) before UV unwrapping it? Could you please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to unwrap an object, if you choose to mark seams, you need to create as many seams as necessary, and put them where you want Blender to cut off the UVs, as if it was peeling an orange. For example here I've cut along all these edges, then unwrap, and it worked fine:

[image]

See the *UV Editor*, with these seams the UVs are rather good. If you want to make a seamless texture you'll need a procedural texture, or you'll need to paint the joint with the stencil option for example:

[image]

Comment: I think you have forgotten the front part, haven't you? The front is still a "half cylinder". This is what creates the weird UV island at the bottom right of your last screenshot. You need to mark an edge loop as a seam as you did on the back.

Comment: Yes I've just done the back part for demonstration  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea how Substance Painter is likely to need it, but this shows the seams I added in wireframe view:
[image]

And this shows the result after unwrapping again:
[image]

Here is the resulting Blend file:
[image]